# Checking for malloc failure when creating a 2D array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

I am trying to check if mallocing fails when creating a 2D Array. This is what i came up with:

```
...
image->imageData = (unsigned int**) malloc(image->height * sizeof(unsigned int*));
// if malloc is unsuccessful, it will return a null pointer
if (image->imageData == NULL) { // check malloc
  image->errorStatus = BAD_MALLOC;
  return image;
} // check malloc

for(int nRow = 0; nRow < image->height; nRow++) {
  image->imageData[nRow] = (unsigned int*) malloc(image->width * sizeof(unsigned int));
  // if malloc is unsuccessful, it will return a null pointer
  if (image->imageData[nRow] == NULL) { // check malloc
    image->errorStatus = BAD_MALLOC;
    return image;
  } // check malloc
}
...
```

The case for malloc failing is if image dimensions are too high (image->height and image->width) causing the program to run out of memory. I know this code snippet can't detect it because image->errorStatus is set to something else (further down the program) when I replicate the case. My question is why is this code snippet not able to detect malloc failure.

Comment: There is no question in your post. Ask a specific question.

Comment: Isnt easier to just return error code.

Comment: You do not allocate 2D array only array of pointers. It is something completely different. BTW it is very unlikely `malloc` to fail as it (on many systems) does allocate the memory. The memory is allocated on the first attempt to use this memory.

Comment: This code snippet can't detect malloc failure even if it happens. I want to know why. @EricPostpischil

Comment: malloc is very unlikely to fail. If you want to be sure - allocate and access at least every MB)

Comment: I have a specific test script that makes it so malloc fails and this code can not detect it. @0___________

Comment: @studentofquran I think you do not understand

Comment: change malloc to calloc - it will access the memory and **actually** allocate it.

Comment: @0___________: not really. `calloc` may return a block of memory with all pages mapped to the same zero filled page with map and copy on write semantics.

Comment: @chqrlie indeed. So the only way is manually touch the allocated block in some intervals

Comment: @0___________: touching the pages is just going to ensure the memory is mapped, it will not really detect allocation failure. The program may become very slow and eventually crash if memory is overcommitted by a lot.  This behavior depends on the OS.

Comment: make your life easier and allocate a true 2D array with a single allocation using a pointer to VLA. Do `unsigned int (*image)[width] = calloc(height, sizeof *image)`

Answer (score 2):

If allocation fails for a row, you should free the memory allocated so far and return `NULL`.  If `image` is allocated, it should be freed and return `NULL`.

```
struct Image *alloc_iamge(int heigth, int width) {
    struct Image *image = calloc(1, sizeof(*image));
    if (image == NULL)
        return NULL;
    image->height = height;
    image->width = width;
    image->imageData = malloc(image->height * sizeof(unsigned int*));
    // if malloc is unsuccessful, it will return a null pointer
    if (image->imageData == NULL) { // check malloc
        free(image);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int nRow = 0; nRow < image->height; nRow++) {
        image->imageData[nRow] = calloc(image->width, sizeof(unsigned int));
        // if malloc is unsuccessful, it will return a null pointer
        if (image->imageData[nRow] == NULL) {
            while (nRow > 0) {
                free(image->imageData[--nRow]);
                image->imageData[nRow] = NULL;
            }
            free(image->imageData)
            image->imageData = NULL;
            free(image);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return image;
}
```

If memory allocation fails, `malloc` or `calloc` will return `NULL`. On modern operating systems, this occurs if the allocation size exceeds the quota available to the process. If `malloc` succeeds, the memory may be accessed but might not be available yet: the memory may be overcommitted, ie: pages will be mapped to the process address space later, when they are written to, and some other pages of the same or another process will be reclaimed as needed. Code pages and file cache pages will just be reused and data pages will be written to the swap file for later reload.  Other memory management techniques may be used to optimize memory use such as in memory compression (eg: macOS).

Comment: This is handled somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Good change to calloc which **will** allocate memory, not only promise it.

Comment: @studentofquran: here-above is a standalone function to allocate an image structure.  You should write functions for elementary tasks and post a complete program that displays the problem.

Comment: @0___________: I'm afraid there is no difference between `malloc` and `calloc` in terms of overcommitting.  For large quantities, the memory does not get mmapped until it is effectively written to.

Comment: @chqrlie callock should write it I believe

Comment: @0___________: it depends on the size allocated and the system allocation strategy.  I have seen very surprising yet efficient schemes where a large calloced block had all pages mapped to the same area until they get written to.